# How can a calendar refresh/reload after a event was changed?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm changing a event using the CalendarApp script, but it seems it appears on the Calendar UI only after a random time, ranging from seconds to minutes. Is there a way to force the event to be updated/refresh on the Calendar immediately after it was changed on the script?

I tried using several combinations of

```
  cal.setHidden(true);
  cal.setHidden(false);
  cal.setSelected(false);
  cal.setSelected(true);
  CalendarApp.setHidden(true);
  CalendarApp.setHidden(false);
  CalendarApp.setSelected(false);
  CalendarApp.setSelected(true);
```

but I still have inconcistent results. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar service and the calendar Browser Ui are two separate things, they have no relationship except being linked to the same source (the calendar itself), there is no way for a script to interact with the calendar Ui... You can use the refresh button under "more" menu in the upper right corner of Calendar Ui but that is all you can do.